# Repeat array object elements by an array property

Tags: javascript, lodash

My problem goes this way; I have an array of courses, each one has its name and array consisting of lessons (Each lesson has its own days).

I.e.:

```
courses = [
  {name: 'Math', lessons: [{day: 'Wednesday'}, {day: 'Thursday'}]},
  {name: 'Sports', lessons: [{day: 'Monday'}]}
]
```

My desired result is:

```
courses_flattened = [
  {name: 'Math', lesson: {day: 'Wednesday'}},
  {name: 'Math', lesson: {day: 'Thursday'}},
  {name: 'Sports', lesson: {day: 'Monday'}}
]
```

Currently what I'm doing is using array.map to iterate over the courses, then for each course I'm returning an array consisting of all lessons times.
After receiving an array of arrays, I'm using:

```
courses_flattened = [].concat.apply([], courses_flat)
```

to get an array consisting of all courses with 1 lesson each.

Full code:

```
courses_flat = courses.map((course) -> {
  var lessons = [];
  course.lessons.forEach((lesson) -> {
    lessons.push({name: course.name, lesson: {day: lesson.day}})
  });
  return lessons;
});
```

Is there a nicer way for receiving this kind of result?

Using Lodash is an option for me.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why?

Comment: @JonasW.  Indeed, this was a perfectly explained question.  The only reason I can think of the downvote is it's maybe best in code review.

Comment: The close vote is even more funny... How can this be "to broad" ??!

Answer (score 2):

Nested loops can be rewritten with `flatMap`. It's not built-in in JS, but you can define it easily like this:

```
let flatMap = (a, fn) => [].concat(...a.map(fn));
```

(Note that this is essentially your `[].concat.apply` thing).

and then

```
courses_flattened = flatMap(courses, ({name, lessons}) => 
     lessons.map(lesson => ({name, lesson})));
```

With lodash it's the same:

```
courses_flattened = _.flatMap(courses, ({name, lessons}) => 
     _.map(lessons, lesson => ({name, lesson})));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const courses = [
  {name: 'Math', lessons: [{day: 'Wednesday'}, {day: 'Thursday'}]},
  {name: 'Sports', lessons: [{day: 'Monday'}]}
];

const result = [];

for(const {name, lessons} of courses)
  for(const {day} of lessons)
    result.push({name, lesson: { day }});
    
console.log(result);
```

Just use two nested for loops maybe? ( And object destructuring)

Comment: Such lovely code, would look much more lovely inside a snippet.. :)

Comment: @keith because then you dont even need to read through it to check if it works, you can just click on "run snippet", check the result, copy + paste and ask the next question... But yes, the `<>` button does not exist on touch devices..

Answer (score 0):

In plain ES6 JavaScript you could use `reduce`, `map` and destructuring to get to this solution:

```js
const courses = [{name: 'Math', lessons: [{day: 'Wednesday'}, {day: 'Thursday'}]},{name: 'Sports', lessons: [{day: 'Monday'}]}];

const result = courses.reduce( (acc, {name, lessons}) =>
    acc.concat(lessons.map( lesson => ({ name, lesson }) ))
, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```